# zoom functionality problems

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscintilla

i am creating a text editor (as so many do) and right now i am trying to implement a zoom function, only to run into a problem. it is a bit difficult to explain but basiclly when zooming in the Qtextbox ends up going under an overlaid box, what i believe to be the QGraphicsScene functions doing. i couldnt find a way to work around this function, and have no way of confirming that it is the problem.

for clarity i want the page zoom in to act like any other word or google doc, making the text box bigger (I'll set a maximum later, the page size is up for change)

heres the important snippet of code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class ToolBar(QToolBar):
    def __init__(self, central_widget):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = central_widget
        self.create_toolbar()

    def create_toolbar(self):
        zoom_in_button = QPushButton("Zoom In", self)
        zoom_in_button.clicked.connect(self.central_widget.zoom_in)

        zoom_out_button = QPushButton("Zoom Out", self)
        zoom_out_button.clicked.connect(self.central_widget.zoom_out)

        reset_zoom_button = QPushButton("Reset Zoom", self)
        reset_zoom_button.clicked.connect(self.central_widget.reset_zoom)

        self.addWidget(zoom_in_button)
        self.addWidget(zoom_out_button)
        self.addWidget(reset_zoom_button)


class ZoomableTextBox(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ZoomableTextBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.text_edit.setFixedSize(500, 800) #placeholder size
        self.scene.addWidget(self.text_edit)

        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.zoom_factor = 1.0

    def zoom_in(self):
        self.zoom_factor *= 1.2
        self.scale(1.2, 1.2)
        self.update_scene_rect()

    def zoom_out(self):
        self.zoom_factor /= 1.2
        self.scale(1 / 1.2, 1 / 1.2)
        self.update_scene_rect()

    def reset_zoom(self):
        self.zoom_factor = 1.0
        self.resetTransform()
        self.update_scene_rect()

    def update_scene_rect(self):
        # Update the scene rectangle to ensure it fits the visible items
        items_rect = self.scene.itemsBoundingRect()
        self.setSceneRect(items_rect)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.text_box = ZoomableTextBox()  # Set self.text_box here
        self.tool_bar = ToolBar(self.text_box)  # Pass self.text_box to the toolbar

        # Add the toolbar to the main window
        self.addToolBar(self.tool_bar)

        # Set the central widget as the text box
        central_widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_box, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addStretch(1)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Set window properties
        self.setWindowTitle('placeholder')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        # Show the window
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why not just hook the buttons up to the `QTextEdit`'s  [`zoomIn`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html#zoomIn) and [`zoomOut`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html#zoomOut)  methods?

Comment: @Alexander That would also change the layout while keeping the page size identical. The OP is trying to get a "real" zoom, while keeping the page *visually* consistent.

Comment: I don't understand your problem: what is the "overlaid box" you're talking about? When you scale the view, the view won't change its size, will only show its contents at a different scale, eventually adding scroll bars to allow viewing the full scene rect while scrolling. Which is exactly what I see in your example.

Comment: @musicamante see thats what im trying to get around, the view (the overlaid box i was trying to describe) stays the same size, i want the page to remain visible when zooming in and the view gets in the way of that. i tried resizing the view and making it the size the window to try and get around it, but couldn't get it working at all. my goal is to allow for resizing too, well the size of the window preferably, before the page goes under the view and the scroll bars come in.

Comment: Your usage of "under the view"&co makes me think that you've not really understood how the Graphics View works. It's a scroll area (similar, but quite different than QScrollArea), which shows *in it* a QGraphicsScene, which can have an arbitrary size (in logical coordinates) and may be scaled in the view: changing the scale in which the scene is shown does *not* change the size of the view. It's like having a magnifier glass that allows you to switch its lens: if you change the lens (to increase or decrease the magnification) that will not change the size of the magnifier glass.

Comment: It's also unclear the reason for the left/right stretches in the layout. Why are you doing that? The view should never be influenced by the scale (at least for the purpose of what you're doing), it should always show as much as possible of the scene, eventually displaying the scroll bars whenever the scene cannot be fully visible, which may depend on the scene size *and* the scaling.

Comment: @musicamante you keep putting words to what i'm trying to ask, thank you! it is the frame of the magnifying glass that i want expanded to the size of the Apps window, whatever the windows size may be. i understand that QGraphicsRectItem() can resize QGraphicsScene, but after trying again and again i can't figure out how to make it the size of the window at all times. i wonder if the answer is obvious and im not seeing it.

Comment: @corryfindel The Graphics View framework is as powerful and extensible as it's complex, with a steep learning curve if you want to use it correctly. I suggest you to start by carefully studying the [reference docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html). *Any* QGraphicsItem (not only QGraphicsRectItem) can potentially resize the graphics scene by expanding it if necessary, *unless* the scene rect is explicitly set. But this has *nothing* to do with the size of the view that shows the scene. If you want to *fit* the view to the window, do what suggested above: remove those `addStretch()`.

Comment: @corryfindel The relation between QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene is similar to that of a Qt item view (such as QTableView) and a model (such as QStandardItemModel): the size of the view is not affected by model changes (or the sizes of its "items"). If you add more rows or columns to a model, or resize one of its header sections (which is similar to expanding the scene rect), the view will still have the same size, and it will just eventually display scroll bars in order to allow access to items currently hidden "behind" the viewport.